Obtaining enriched motif result for each peak using ArchR
I'm analyzing scATAC-seq data using ArchR by following their official manual. in the section "12.1 Motif Enrichment in Differential Peaks", I obtained good results comparing the motif enrichment of differential peaks between two samples for a same cluster of cells. Now, I want to know which peaks were assigned for enrichment of the significant TFs in my results. Is it possible to do that?
I looked into the results returned by peakAnnoEnrichment, but it only contained TFs, p-values and the number of background peaks, etc.

Please show your "good results". Adding a small amount of demonstrative examples helps a lot in attracting good answers.
